# Laptop won't boot anymore

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, freebsd, gparted

I had Ubuntu only on my Laptop and wanted to try FreeBSD out.

My operating system was on `/dev/sdb`. `/dev/sda` was spare and I made a 100GB partition on it with the help of `gparted`. Subsequently I just downloaded the FreeBSD image file and wrote it on a USB (`/dev/sdc`) which I formated beforehand with gparted. I wrote the image file with the dd command on the stick and thought that's it: restart and install.

But when I restarted, after the Lenovo logo, nothing but a black screen and a blinking underscore. I don't understand what went wrong, because I basically didn't do anything critical. The behaviour is the same with or without the stick plugged in. The only thing that came to my mind: I unmounted /dev/sdc in gparted. Does this produce some bad behaviour with dd when I just type:

```
dd if=FreeBSD[fullname].img of=/dev/sdc bs=64k ?
```

Comment: Doesn't matter if you unmounted it. Go into your bios and check your boot order. If that doesn't help, I suggest trying a liveCD of some sort of variant to make sure everything else is working.

Comment: your mbr is on /dev/sda ... what happened to it? If you've cleaned out /dev/sda with gparted, I can only imagine it's gone too

Comment: I don't think so because the hard drive was completely empty. But assuming this is the case, any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so for everyone running into the same problems I will explain the answer I found:
As already mentioned in the comments the Main Boot Record (mbr) was erased. This happened because the mbr, in all standard installations, is found on the primary hard disk (sda in my case). Thus my lightheaded use of gparted destroyed this record. The solution is to reinstantiate it again with a Ubuntu Live-CD. How to do so is found in this nice link:

http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd